# Is it possible on Android to get the list of languages chosen by the user in the system settings?

Tags: android, localization

In the system settings of newer Android versions users can:

1. define one default language
2. specify additional languages which the user understands

[image: Android language preferences]

This kind of multi language preference is very similar to the multi language settings of modern web browsers.

Within an Android app, the default language is accessible by `Locale.getDefault().language`.

The list of all Locales installed on the device is accessible by `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`.

But is there also a way to get the list of preferred languages shown on the screen above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should do:

```java
LocalList locals = getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales ()

for(int i=0; i<locals.size(); i++){
   Log.d("tag",locals.get(i).getDisplayLanguage())
}
```

for more info

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#getLocales()
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

Comment: Great that's what I was looking for! In Kotlin I only had to replace the style of the for loop as follows: `for (i in 0 until locals.size()) Log.d("tag",locals.get(i).getDisplayLanguage())`

Comment: What about previous versions? it is supported from api 24

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala you can use ConfigurationCompat.getLocales: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/os/ConfigurationCompat#getlocales

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
LocaleList locales = LocaleList.getDefault();
```

or for compatibility with API prior 24

```
LocaleListCompat locales = LocaleListCompat.getDefault();
```

then

```
for( int i = 0; i < locales.size(); i++ ) {
    Locale loc = locales.get(i);
    Log.d("lang", loc.getDisplayLanguage(loc) + " (" + loc.getDisplayCountry(loc) + ")");
}
```